# JS - Positive Look Ahead & End Of Line

Tags: javascript, regex

Why is the first test failing?

```
/^[ab](?=[cd])$/.test('ac') // => false

/^[ab](?=[cd])/.test('ac')  // => true
```

Only the string 'ac', 'ad', 'bc' & 'bd' should pass.

No other strings like 'ac bd' or 'acbd'.

However, using the `$` isn't helping in the 1st regex, whereas the 2nd one will also pass for strings like 'acbd'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to understand how look-aheads work.

The `(?=[cd])$` *positive* look-ahead checks if the following characters match the pattern that follows the look-ahead (in your case, the end of string). The end of string is not `c` nor `d`. Thus, there is no match.

You need to put the `$` to the look-ahead to make it match `a`:

```
^[ab](?=[cd]$)
```

See [demo on Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rZ5bQ8/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/C0AQH0sWp3d0a7xo)

Comment: Happy to help. Also, you can read on [look-arounds on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) when you have a bit of free time.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should pass:

```
/^[ab](?=[cd]$)/.test('ac')
```

Reason why

```
/^[ab](?=[cd])$/.test('ac')
```

is failing because `$` (end of input) is not there after `a` or `b` (there is a letter `c` after `a`).

Comment: Hmm case of duplicate answers here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[ab](?=[cd])$/.test('ac') // => false
```

This failed as you did not capture `c`.`Lookahead` are `0` width assertions.They dont capture anything just assert.Your string match fails as you have enabled `anchors` and so whole string should match.In your second case it passes as it gets a partial match as there is no `$`.

What you need is

```
^[ab][cd]$
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that (?=) are not capturing groups.